# sqlite query gives different result in shell compared to python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I run a query in sqlite3 shell

(sorry for the image, but I cannot copy text from the windows command shell for some reason)

[image]

but the same query run from inside python (on the same database) returns no rows.

```
def strange_test(dbf=DBF):
    con = lite.connect(dbf)
    con.row_factory = lite.Row
    with con:
        inputs_sql = "SELECT id, linefill_end FROM T1 WHERE CAST(linefill_end as integer) != linefill_end"
        #inputs_sql = "SELECT id, linefill_end FROM T1 WHERE id = 2307"



        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(inputs_sql)
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row:
            print row[0], row[1]
        else:
            print "Nothing found"

    return row
```

Gives no results:

```
%run "C:/Users/foo/Dropbox/parity_checking.py"
Nothing found
```

I know from the sql shell results that record number 2307 has a non-integer value "not found".  If I query that record specifically from inside Python, it also shows the value as "not found". I think this proves they're looking at the same records.   So why does the query make results in the shell, but not inside python??!?!?  Does somehow cast() not work properly when called from python?

```
def strange_test(dbf=DBF):
    con = lite.connect(dbf)
    con.row_factory = lite.Row
    with con:
        #inputs_sql = "SELECT id, linefill_end FROM T1 WHERE CAST(linefill_end as integer) != linefill_end"

        """search for a record I know has a non-integer linefill_end value"""
        inputs_sql = "SELECT id, linefill_end FROM T1 WHERE id = 2307"



        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(inputs_sql)
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row:
            print row[0], row[1]
        else:
            print "Nothing found"

    return row



%run "C:/Users/foo/Dropbox/_python/parity_checking.py"
2307 not found
```

Comment: Why are you calling cur.execute twice?

Comment: to be clear, I am using  "import sqlite3 as lite"

Comment: Don't you need the trailing `;` at the end in SQLite? Lib probably auto-completes but you can never be to sure. Was a while since i worked with file-databases.

Comment: @Torxed no, the trailing semicolon is not required. Tried it anyway, didn't make a different

Comment: @roymustang86 not calling it twice intentionally. I removed duplication and still get the same behavior

Comment: My SQL is quite rusty, but if all the values are "not found", could the casting make it return nothing? Anyway, I think the problem here is that your code is not equivalent to your sqlite command, since you are fetching just the first element with fetchone(), you should fetch until done with the whole set of lines. That explains also why selecting a single item works, since you are fetching that particular item.

Comment: @Jblasco " rows = cur.fetchall()" still exhibits same behavior -- nothing found.   I made a simple query inputs_sql = "SELECT id, linefill_end FROM T1 WHERE id < 2307" and the fetchall() does return an object.

Comment: @Jblasco  and to be clear, the "not found" is a string value in the column.

Comment: In the malfunctioning query you are comparing integer to a string, which is not a safe operation. I never worked with sqlite, but try to cast your integer back to string in the WHERE clause, see if that helps.

Comment: @Muposat the intention of the query is to find all the rows in that column that aren't integers.  Unfortunately the column is a TEXT column.

Comment: @user3556757 That's not my point. Try this in the non-working query: `WHERE CAST(CAST(linefill_end as integer) as text) != linefill_end`, this way you are comparing text to text which is a safer operation. This is just a hunch but worth a try.

Comment: @Muposat  I used your query, "SELECT id, linefill_end FROM T1 WHERE CAST(CAST(linefill_end as integer) as text) != linefill_end"  but afraid it gave the same answer -- no results found

Comment: @Torxed A trailing semicolon is required by the SQL standard, but optional in SQLite (and most other databases). In any case, it cannot hurt.

Comment: @Muposat Comparing integers with strings is well defined (always returns false).

Comment: Works for me (with a short program that does just CREATE TABLE, INSERT, and SELECT).

Comment: First modify your code to be equivalent to that of the SQL command, then we can continue guessing here. One way forward, though, would be to start doing 'edits' in your original question, letting everyone know what you have tried and the results. The famous ; at the end of the line, for example, seems to be distracting people, so just put it there. The attempt to read fetchall that I suggested, did you print the whole of row? The part of the "if row" is obviously not doing any good, do "print row" and post what happens... You need to help us help you!